# Navigation architecture not using single Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have implemented `Navigation Architecture` Framework to display couple of fragments. Unfortunately each fragment is creating a new activity. 
So I started the `Activity` with `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`
and `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` flags but they didnt helped much as using them won't show any fragment after showing for the first time only.

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/notification_nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/openingNotificationFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/standByScreenFragment"
            android:name="com.emaz.android.ui.notification.standby.StandByScreenFragment"
            android:label="StandByScreenFragment" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/welcomeNotificationFragment"
            android:name="com.emaz.android.ui.notification.welcome.WelcomeNotificationFragment"
            android:label="WelcomeNotificationFragment" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/openingNotificationFragment"
            android:name="com.emaz.android.ui.notification.ingress..OpeningNotificationFragment"
            android:label="OpeningFragment" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/closingNotificationFragment"
            android:name="com.emaz.android.ui.notification.ingress..ClosingNotificationFragment"
            android:label="ClosingNotificationFragment" />
    </navigation>
```

**HomeActivity**
Calling `NotificationActivity` as

```
val intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                startActivity(intent)
```

**NotificationActivity**
And calling fragments as

```
notification_container.visibility = View.GONE
            fragment_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, nav_host_fragment.id)

            navController.popBackStack()
            Log.e("nav", "${navController.currentDestination} and $resId < ResourceId")

            navController.navigate(resId, null)
```

I could see the `resId` changing but couldnt see on the screen.
Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate by calling `startActivity`? If you are using navigation component you should just use `navController.navigate` to navigate from one fragment to another one.

Comment: There is an external trigger which starts the activity, but I am calling the method inside the activity to navigate to the specific fragment. If I don't use activity flags then navigation shows the fragment but it does not dismisses the old fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the multiple activity creation issue. For other people who face same problem. Make sure the app is not in background if you are trying to navigate to fragment using navigation architecture.

Keeping the app active would not create new instance of the activity and app would work as expected.